# Proving that a trigonometric sum is in $L^2$

Tags: analysis, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, lebesgue-integral

How can I use Parseval's identity to prove that
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)}{1+k}$$ is in $L^2(0,\pi)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Parseval's Theorem, we have

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}f(x)^2dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^2$$

Since the series converges, then $f$ is in $\mathscr{L}^2$

---

We can show this equality as follows

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi}f^2(x) &=\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin kx}{k+1}dx \tag 1\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\int_0^{\pi}f(x)\,\sin(kx)\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{k+1} \tag 3\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

**NOTE: 1**:

$(1)$ uses the Fourier Series representation of $f$.

**NOTE: 2**:

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$, we used the fact that the Fourier coefficients are given by $\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}f(x) \sin (kx)dx$.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.Could you explain the first equation?

I know by Parseval's identity that $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(x)|^2 dx=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f(k)}|^2=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} (\int_0 ^{2\pi} e^{-ixk}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} sin(jx)/(1+j)dx)^2 $$ how can i continue from here?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Carry out the integral.  You can use orthogonality relations between $e^{-kx}$ and $\sin(jx)$ on the interval $0$ to $2\pi$.  But the case in the original post has $0$ to $\pi$ as the interval of interest.

Comment: Isn't Parseval  Identity for functions in  L<sup>2<\sup>? How about the following argument:  Since we know the sum of the square of the coefficients is convergent, by Parseval' Theorem the series is the Fourier series of a unique square integrable function h.  Since the series converges everywhere h is identically f.  So f is square integrable in $[- \pi, \pi]$ and so it is square integrable in $[0, \pi]$.   To justify the computation of the integral of  f <sup>2<\sup>, make use of that the partial sum of the series is uniformly bounded and apply the Lebesgue Bounded Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for the note.  And I do like your argument here!  Aside, I thought that the interval of interest was $[0,\pi]$ and that the Fourier series for $f$ on $[0,\pi]$ is given by $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n+1}$.

Comment: @Dr. MV The interval is not crucial.  It is more incisive to examine the series closely.  One can see that the series converges uniformly on any closed interval free from multiples of $2\pi$. So it converges to a function continuous at points in $[-\pi, \pi] - {0}$ It is 0 at 0.  Furthermore it converges boundedly since its coefficient is of order $O(1/n)$.  So it converges to a Riemann integrable function and so the limit function is square integrable.  I think the question on the use of Parseval identity is misdirected.